# How to replace all words before a particular character in a line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to replace all the words coming before the character '=' in every line of the code in Notepad++?

Comment: @downvoter, just out of curiosity, what's wrong with this question, other than it is sounds very "basic"?

Comment: I think this question might be considered a duplication. Really, how long would it take to google the answer (maybe not exactly the very same situation) to such question? Other than that, I think it is a completely correct question in StackOverflow, unless proved otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with regular expressions.

Find what: `^[\w\s]+\=(.*)$`
Replace with: `newword\=\1`.
See the screenshot below for more information:

[image: Replace all words before '=' symbol]

You should enter your desired replacement word instead of "newword" in the regular expression.