# how to replace text before the char < in every line in notepad++ using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

In notepad++ I have a lot of lines, and some lines contain the character <
What I want is to delete all characters before the < in each line.

I found a very similar question with answer here :
[How to replace all words before a particular character in a line in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975440/how-to-replace-all-words-before-a-particular-character-in-a-line-in-notepad)
But I failed in modifying the regex with what I need.

In that answer the regex = `^[\w\s]+\=(.*)$`
So I tried replacing the = by < like this `^[\w\s]+\<(.*)$` but it does not works.

here is some sample data from the document :

```
test123@t-online.de
'hello' <hello@apollo.com
```

and here is my desired outcome

```
test123@t-online.de
hello@apollo.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to replace any chars up to `<`, you may use even simpler regex:

```
^.*?<
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/MCO4Gg/2